# Error while uploading Image in Custom module

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I have created a custom module in Magento 2.While uploading image I get an error.

> A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

[image]

if anybody knows what would be the reason?

Comment: were you able to upload the image? or just you see this error but the image are uplaoded

Comment: how do i check if image is uploaded or not?

Comment: in your controller, you should have the way that you save the image , try to check your controller